# Filling space with centered, fixed-width div

Tags: html, css

I want to create a layout with three `<div>`s, whereby my second (middle) div has a fixed width (e.g. 300px). My other two `<div>`s, should equally **fill** the rest of the parent element.

I'd love to solve it with some kind of percentages for the left and right `<div>`s, so it is horizontally scaleable.

```
<div>
    <div class="rest"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="rest"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `width` property of the other two `<div>`s to `calc(50% - 150px);`.

```
div.rest {
    width: calc(50% - 150px);
    width: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);
    width: -o-calc(50% - 150px);
    width: -moz-calc(50% - 150px);
}
```

See [this example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6puqnuk/2/).

Comment: Nice! I'm new to Html/Css. Calc seems like a great option here. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickObermueller Yup, I'm glad it helped. I'll upload an example in a few moments...